# /Users/rstu/workspace/.../main.cpp:38:13: No matching conversion for C-style cast from 'void' to 'std::__1::basic_string<char>'

Tags: c++, c++11

It works for `int`, but not for `std::string`?
I do not understand the following error (what am I doing wrong?):

```
template <class T> class Stack {
private:
    vector<T> elems;
public:
    void push(T const&);
    T pop();
};

template <class T> void Stack<T>::push (T const& elem) {
    elems.push_back(elem);
}

template <class T> T Stack<T>::pop () {
    if (elems.empty()) {
        throw out_of_range("Stack<>::pop(): empty stack");
    }
    T ret = (T)elems.pop_back();         /* <--- ERROR! <<================ */
    return ret;           
}

main(){
...
        string X = stringStack.pop();
        stringStack.pop();
...
}
```

> Error: No matching conversion for C-style cast from 'void' to 'std::__1::basic_string'

Comment: `vector.back()` then pop is what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sometimes you are really blind ... Somehow I deleted the line :-)))

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for [`vector<T>::pop_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back).  It doesn't return anything.